# How to get Eclipse code completion back after switching target to GoogleAPIs?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps-api-3

In order to make use of Google API [GeoPoints](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/GeoPoint.html) in my Android app, I just changed the application target from this:

```
# In project.properties
# Project Target
target=android-8
```

to this:

```
# In project.properties
# Project Target
target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:14
```

After changing the target to Google APIs, it wasn't long before I noticed that **code completion wasn't there anymore**. Anybody know if it is possible to get Android API code completion when targeting Google APIs?

**Update:** 
Just tried again and now I am getting code completion. Strange...

Comment: I use Google API targets with code completion, without applying any fixes, so it definitely is possible. What version of Eclipse are you using? Have you tried restarting Eclipse?

Comment: I did not even need to restart. After some time it (code completion) just was there again. Maybe when the targets are switched, Eclipse lazily loads some code completion resources in the background -- and was not immediately ready. I dunno. Thanks for your help anyways @Craigy!

Comment: can you please explain what is code completion? what are u referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right click on project folder, go to properties, select android. set project target to 14 from 8.

restart eclipse if needed.

Check min sdk version in manifest file (it should be 14, if not make it),

then project or default.properties (change as you wrote in your question, if not there)